# Ionic 2 Save base64 to ios camera roll

Tags: android, ios, angular, cordova, ionic2

I have been trying for a whle now to find a decent solution to save a base64 string to an iphone / android camera roll.

I am aware you can do this directly from the camera by setting saveToPhotoAlbum to true, but i need to be able to put the image onto a canvas and ass some overlays / text to the image before saving. Anyone got a solotion that actualy works (in regardst to saving the data?

Thanks

Comment: To a camera roll? What´s that? What would be the result?

Comment: To the gallery of the camera, ie where all your other images are kept. or it could be stored in its own directory, i dont mind.

Comment: `To the gallery of the camera, ie where all your other images are kept.` Such storage location does not exist on an Android device. The Gallery app is an app. No storage location. The Gallery app shows all the media on the device. From a lot of folders/directories.

Comment: But i'm not aware that the Gallery app can handle base64 images. Never seen such. Under which extension would you save such string to file?

Comment: Ok. Basically, this is what i want to achieve. I want to take a photo, layer over some text / transparent background and then save it to the phone. Currently, i have the image from the photo and i am using a canvas to position the text etc. The canvas can then spit back a base64 image. am not sure if this is the best way to do it?

Comment: `Currently, i have the image from the photo` You could tell how you obtained that as we know very little of what you are doing. What do you mean exactly with 'image'? What do you mean exactly with 'photo'? What is it that you have already? A bitmap?

Comment: like this Camera.getPicture({
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      quality: 100,
      targetWidth: 200,
      targetHeight: 200,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      allowEdit: true
    }).then((imageData) => {
};

Comment: Sorry. Never saw that camera class.